# Decorator to pass pandas Series into one-column DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, python-decorators

I want to write a decorator that I can use on functions that are written for Pandas DataFrame, so that when they receive an input that is actually a Series (or maybe even an array) it first transforms that input into a one-column Pandas DataFrame out of generality. That way I can make every function work for both DataFrames and series writing functions only for DataFrames.

Something like

```
@wraps
def does_smt(df, **kwargs):
    for c in df.columns:
        df[c] = do_something(df[c], df.index)
    return df

does_smt(series) # and it also works
```

I'm not too good with python decorators yet, but judging by Pint's [ureg.wraps](http://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.2/wrapping.html) decorator I'm thinking it can be done. I checked that decorator but, then again, since I'm having trouble understanding decorators, I couldn't figure out how to adapt that. I also searched for a decorator like that already defined in Pandas but there seems to be none.

First question: How can I do that?

Second: Is that recommended, or is there a better way?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@First question: How can I do that?**

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import wraps

def seriescapable(func):
    """Decorator for turning the first argument from a pandas.Series to a pandas.DataFrame."""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], pd.Series):
            return = func(pd.DataFrame(args[0]), *args[1:], **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


# Usage example:

@seriescapable
def my_func(df):
    print type(df)
    print df

myfunc(pd.Series([1, 2]))
```

See also [Python Cookbook: Putting a wrapper around a function](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch09.html#_putting_a_wrapper_around_a_function)

**@Second question: Is that recommended, or is there a better way?**

I see no fundamental problem with the procedure. Semantically, it's clear enough and at least type checking is used as an example in [PEP-318 -- Decorators for Functions and Methods](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). It adds a bit of processing overhead, but likely that's negligible compared to the calculation you'll perform within the function. For reference, here is also a [more general solution for automatic argument conversion](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/355806-automatic-argument-type-conversion/).

Comment: Thank you. That general solution is also pretty neat, although I'm probably going to use yours. Also, I know that wasn't in the question (I'll edit or ask another question if you want), but in case the input in a Series, is there a way of re-converting the output to a Series in the end?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! That link you gave me is actually really good explaining decorators. I don't know why I never tried the python Cookbook. Anyway, thanks again.